# Free jQuery Grid which supports frozen columns and dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, dojo

I checked few jQuery Grid which supports frozen columns like jqGrid. But I want any easy to use jQuery or any other Javascript library Grid plugin (like Dojo etc.) with following support:

1. Free
2. Ability to add columns dynamically.
3. Good integration with ASP.NET.
4. Frozen columns.

Comment: What do you mean by "Good integration with ASP.NET" ? Most of the JavaScript grids I have seen have no particular support for specific server-side languages.

Comment: @david Actually I mean there should be anyway to send column names easily at run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net) with ASP.NET...probably more than we should as it's just too easy to use. It works very well and does support frozen columns with a plugin. I haven't found any JS table plugin that I like as well.

Comment: that seems good but it shows examples using PHP. I want to learn how to use it with ASP.NET, rather send column names at run-time from code-behind to JSON.

Comment: @RKh: just create your data structure such that you can build your column names that way: Mine looks roughly like `{Columns: [array, of, column, names], Rows: [[2d, array, of, data],[another, row, of, data]]}`... I realize that isn't valid JSON, but you get the drift. So then in your DataTables init: `aaData` is `msg.d.Rows` and you'll build your aoColumns definition with `msg.d.Columns`.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can post a complete answer on it.